# Why does my Java heap dump show only half the heap?

Tags: java, heap-memory

I'm intentionally adding items to a data structure until Java throws an `OutOfMemoryError`, and grabbing a heap dump using `-XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError`.  I'm using `-Xmx100M`, so I expected the heap dump would show nearly 100MB of live objects, but instead it shows only 46MB.

Why would Java throw OOM with a 100MB heap if there are only 46MB of live objects?

(I realize there's a good chance I haven't given enough information to answer this question, but I'm not sure what's relevant.  Happy to add more info as needed.)

EDIT:  The end of the `-verbose:gc` output:

```
 [Full GC (Ergonomics) [PSYoungGen: 1056K->64K(2560K)] [ParOldGen: 7116K->7116K(7168K)] 8173K->7180K(9728K), [Metaspace: 5981K->5981K(1056768K)], 0.0071141 secs] [Times: user=0.00 sys=0.00, real=0.01 secs] 
 [Full GC (Allocation Failure) [PSYoungGen: 64K->0K(2560K)] [ParOldGen: 7116K->7075K(7168K)] 7180K->7075K(9728K), [Metaspace: 5981K->5974K(1056768K)], 0.0190392 secs] [Times: user=0.02 sys=0.00, real=0.02 secs] 
 java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
```

Comment: You can get OutOfMemoryErrors for a number of reasons, including running out of heap space.  What is the actual error you are getting?

Comment: Hi Peter.  It's this: `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at java.util.Arrays.copyOf(Arrays.java:3308)`

Comment: If you fail to produce a large array, you will get a dump dump without that array.  BTW a 100 MB is a tiny heap these days, are you sure you need it to be that small?

Comment: Hi Peter.  It probably won't be that small in production (though we might do some experiments with AWS "nano" instances, so it might be close).  I just didn't want to wait five minutes to fill memory.

Comment: I would check the size of the array it is trying to copy. If the heap is too small you will get error in places you wouldn't get in production.

Comment: FYI this workload has a small number (a dozen or so) of large primitive arrays occupying most of the heap.  It's a weird one.  Actually, I think you might be on to something, since these arrays double in size when they fill.

Comment: Which suggests you can't reduce the heap size very much and expect it to still work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Heap is split into two sections young generation and old generation. You get OOM when e.g. the old generation is full or fragmented in such way that it is impossible to promote object from young generation to the old (and probably others).

If you log GC usage using e.g. `-verbose:gc -XX:+PrintGCDetails -Xloggc:gc.log` then you will see each generation sizes.

You can see how to tune generation sizes here https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/vm/gctuning/sizing.html

Comment: Thanks for the link!  I would have thought they'd automatically shrink the young generation in a stress scenario like mine.  Setting `-XX:NewRatio=50` or `-XX:MaxNewSize=1M` both end up getting over 90MB of live objects in the heap dump, which makes perfect sense.